# Search for words in text, and replace them

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time finding the solution to my problem.

I have an array like this in a variable:

```
$myarray = Array (
[0] => Orange
[1] => Black
[2] => White
[3] => Yellow
[4] => Red
);
```

Basically, I need search the words of the array in the string, and replace them with the same ones, but with links.

For example, from:

```
$string = "My content contains orange and also blue";
```

To:

```
$string = "My content contains <a href="www.domain.com/orange">orange</a> and also blue";
```

Comment: Why did `black` change to `blue` instead of getting a link?

Comment: @Ericki how could you give the link for orange, where are the link are from?

Comment: @Ericki check my answer and accept it, if really helps

Comment: @Nick In fact, it was just blue. adjusted

Comment: What if a word ins contained in another e.g. `blackout`. Should it still be replaced?

Comment: @Nick good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best achieved using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). We can create a regex by using [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) to create an alternation of each of the words in `$myarray`; capture that word in a group and then use it in the replacement to add the link around it:

```
$string = "My content contains orange and also blue in a blackout";

$string = preg_replace('/\b(' . implode('|', $myarray) . ')\b/i', '<a href="www.domain.com/$1">$1</a>', $string);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
My content contains <a href="www.domain.com/orange">orange</a> and also blue in a blackout
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/i2Zsd)

Note that by using a regex with word boundaries (`\b`) we can avoid unintentionally replacing `black` in `blackout` with a link.

Comment: This is the best answer. It should also return the color in the same case as it was in the text. The replace method will make `Orange` => `orange`

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the support - I think it's the best strategy too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_ireplace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) and do it using arrays:

```
$from = array(
    "Orange",
    "Black",
    "White",
    "Yellow",
    "Red"
);

$to = array(
    '<a href="www.domain.com/orange">orange</a> ',
    '<a href="www.domain.com/black">black</a>',
    '<a href="www.domain.com/white">white</a>',
    '<a href="www.domain.com/yellow">yellow</a>',
    '<a href="www.domain.com/red">red</a>'
);

$string = str_ireplace($from, $to, $string);
```

Edit 1: This also replaces all strings if they are met inside the array, meaning that if you have orange and black in the string, those two will get replaced.

Comment: what if the `$from` has more than 50 records, so I manually need to create the `$to` as copy and edit?

Comment: @DroidDev Oh yes! It's actually str_ireplace =) Good catch!

Comment: @BosnianCoder Perfect. It did the job. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the additional question, but I really have no idea how to do it. But, once the word was found inside the string, would there be a way to remove it from the list of arrays so that there is no more than one match?

Comment: @Ericki This requires using preg_replace which is a performance killer, you can read the article about doing that here: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-replace-only-the-first-occurance-of-a-string-in-php

Edit 1: I should also mention there is a different way of doing that using substr_replace, which is also shown in the article.

Good luck!

Comment: @BosnianCoder This will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Ericki notice that str_replace will do "dumb" replacements that you don't want. See the example Nick posted https://3v4l.org/tYps7 notice the "blackout" part

Comment: @Andreas This is fairly a easy fix, just replace the $from array with " Orange ", " Black ", etc.. https://3v4l.org/6REfO

Comment: @BosnianCoder so what happens if the string is `Red car for sale, the seats are blue.`? Are you going to make exceptions for that too?

Comment: @Andreas The order of the array can get over that problem too. Though I do not assume my way of doing things will be acceptable by everyone else, problem solving has a lot of things going on and because of that has its own ways, just like we all do =)

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to create a way for str_replace to work as expected in this case. `Red`, `reD`, `REd` are just some cases and add to that `,`, `-`, `.` and all other ways to write a sentence.

Comment: @Andreas This is not str_replace (case-senstive), it's str_ireplace (case-insensitive), and yes you are making a good point, but looking at what the person asked, I think this answer is fine. IMO

Comment: But to make it case correct str_ireplace won't work. This it's out of the question

Answer (score -1):

You can use str_ireplace, check the [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

```
$string = "My content contains orange and also black";
$string = str_ireplace("orange","<a href='http://www.example.com/orange'>orange</a>",$string);
```

**EDIT**

As @Ericki has edited the question, please use the below code to achieve the same,

```
$myarray = array (
'Orange','Black','White','Yellow','Red'
);
$string = "My content contains Orange, Black, Yellow, Red";

foreach($myarray as $item){
    if (strpos($string, $item)) {
        $string = str_ireplace($item,"<a href='http://www.example.com/".$item."'>$item</a>",$string);
    }
}   
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: Your answer should be a comment, and it should point to php.net, not w3schools.

Comment: @user3783243 why whats is the reason?

Comment: @DroidDev I tried several times using str_replace, but it doesn't work. I'm still starting out in PHP, so I don't know why that is. Maybe it's because it's not simple arrays? Also, I'm using a very large number of arrays to do what I need (maybe 200), is that why? Well, I don't know. But with str_ireplace it was possible to do. Thank you for the answer.